# Wort gesucht. "Heuchlerisch" passt nicht zu 100%

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche nach einem einzelnen Adjektiv für eine Person, die zwar immer wieder bestimmte (gute) Dinge tut, mit denen sie sich brüstet, aber diese auf eine Art und Weise darstellt, die suggeriert, sie habe etwas noch viel Besseres getan oder das was sie getan hat sei weitaus höher zu bewerten als es eigentlich ist.

Es ist aber nicht wirklich angeberisch, weil es nicht diese Intention hat, Bewunderung hervorzurufen, sondern eher, sich seiner eigenen guten Taten vor sich selbst zu versichern.

Am ehesten finde ich passt das Wort heuchlerisch, allerdings impliziert das, dass die Person vorgibt etwas zu sein oder zu tun, das sie überhaupt nicht tut.

Ich suche also gewissermaßen nach einer Mischung aus heuchlerisch und angeberisch, die beide in diesem Kontext nicht zu 100% passen.

Comment: Laut Wikipedia: "Heuchelei (Hypokrisie) bezeichnet ein [...] Verhalten, bei dem eine Person absichtlich nach außen hin ein Bild von sich vermittelt, das nicht ihrem realen Selbst entspricht. Das zugrundeliegende Zeitwort heucheln stammt ursprünglich vom unterwürfigen ducken und kriechen (mittelhochdeutsch hüchen) des Hundes ab und wurde auf vorgespieltes, schmeichelndes Verhalten übertragen." - Insofern trifft "heuchlerisch" ins Schwarze, es kommt Dir nur so vor, als wäre das zu negativ besetzt! ;)

Comment: Hier noch mehr: https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/eingebildet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Als Ergänzung zu @user55799 auch profilneurotisch ==> Profilneurose.

Comment: Du sagst zwar, es ist nur eine Ergänzung, aber es ist die perfekte Antwort. Profilierend kommt wohl aufs selbe raus, klingt aber ein wenig hölzern.

Answer (score 3):

Ich denke es gibt kaum einen positiven Begriff dafür, da diese Eigenschaft zu Recht eher negativ belegt ist. Wer sich halt am besten verkauft, kommt auch weiter. Allerdings ist das eine Kunst, die sehr subtil ist, und sehr viele Facetten hat, die es manchmal schwer machen das Verhältnis zwischen Übertreibung und Realität zu bewerten.

"heuchlerisch" ist in der Tat äußerst negativ belegt und eher ungeeignet. Das zeigen auch die [Synonyme](http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/heuchlerisch.php). "angeberisch" ist auch relativ negativ.

Mir fällt kein wirklich gutes Adjektiv ein, ich sehe nur die Möglichkeit genauer zu umschreiben:

> Er neigt zu verstärkter [Selbstdarstellung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selbstdarstellung). » selbstdarstellerisch

Vlt. auch gut:

> Er hat einen überhöhten Geltungsdrang ohne heuchlerisch zu wirken.

Eher selten: Selbstinszenierung

Answer (score 2):

Vielleicht: sich profilieren? Also dann als Adjektiv: profilierend

Answer (score 2):

"profilneurotisch" macht mir die Sache zu "krankhaft" oder zu "therapiebedürftig". Wenn dir wirklich wichtig ist, dass die betreffende Person im Wesentlichen unsicher ist, das Verhalten also gewissermaßen auf einer "menschlichen Schwäche" beruht, könntest du es mit "fassadenhaft" versuchen.

Answer (score 0):

Wie wärs mit "überheblich"? Dies bedeutet, dass man die eigene Leistung / das eigene Wissen / den eigenen Status deutlich höher kommuniziert als eigentlich angemessen wäre.